Create a GPS in real life and connect it with a Flutter app
I created a mobile app in Flutter. The app is a tracking, location, and points on the Google map app. However, I am currently limited because, to get the location of people, they need to use their phones. The problem is that this is causing issues because some people run out of battery, don't activate location, or simply don't know how to grant location permissions.
The solution I want is to create a GPS device, but I don't know how to do it. I researched and found out that I can do it with Arduino by buying a GPS module or GPSM, but I'm not sure if it will work for my Flutter app. I also saw that there are some pre-made GPS devices that might have a developer API.
Could someone guide me or let me know if it is possible to create the GPS and connect it to my Flutter app?
I have researched creating a GPS device using Arduino and a GPS module (like the U-blox NEO-6M). I expected to be able to integrate this hardware with my Flutter app to get accurate location data without relying on users' phones. However, I am unsure if this setup will work seamlessly with Flutter. Additionally, I explored pre-made GPS devices that offer developer APIs, expecting them to provide an easier integration process.
What I tried:
Reading articles and watching tutorials on integrating GPS modules with Arduino.
Looking into GPS devices that come with developer APIs.
What I expected:
To find a clear method to connect the Arduino-based GPS to my Flutter app.
To find a pre-made GPS device that can easily integrate with Flutter using its API.
What actually happened:
I found information on connecting GPS modules to Arduino, but I am unsure how to relay that data to the Flutter app.
I found some GPS devices with APIs but am uncertain about their compatibility and ease of use with Flutter.
Could someone guide me on how to proceed with either creating a GPS device and connecting it to Flutter or using a pre-made GPS device with a developer API?
